# Use a static force layout to create a network in Svelte and d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svelte

I've [this network](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-forest-52963d) that works good enough: node position is correctly updated when window width and height change.

Now I'm trying to make it fixed, I mean to compute `n` ticks once and render the network after `n` ticks are computed.

I'm not interested to visualize this intermediate steps:
[image]

I would like just this:

[image]

At the moment the network is computed with 300 ticks (the default value), suppose I want only 100 ticks, I know the nodes won't be in the optimal position but I don't care, I don't want to compute more ticks.
How can I do that?

I tried commented the `tick` event and adding `.tick(100).stop()` but the network is not centered anymore.

```js
  //.on("tick", simulationUpdate)
  .tick(100)
  .stop()
```

I think because the render object has not updated, but I can I do that?

D3 documentation says:

> **simulation.tick([iterations])**
>
> ...
> This method does not dispatch events; events are only dispatched by the internal timer when the simulation
> is started automatically upon creation or by calling
> simulation.restart. The natural number of ticks when the simulation is
> started is ⌈log(alphaMin) / log(1 - alphaDecay)⌉; by default, this is
> 300.
> ...

Comment: (You only need one `{#if simulation}` block in `Graph`, they can be merged.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of a single ticks is very small; so you might want to increase that to about `1000`.

```js
  .tick(1000).stop()
```

You do not need to listen to the `tick` event, but you must force a tick and a re-render when the size changes:

```js
  $: {
    simulation
      .force("center")
      .x(width / 2)
      .y(height / 2);
    simulation.tick();
    simulationUpdate();
  }
```